# Localization in tx_news extension TYPO3 6

Tags: localization, typo3, fluid, extbase

I'm using News System Extension 2.1 for my website. My TYPO3 version is 6.1.

The language key taken by tx_news is `default`, I would like to change the key to `dk or nl or something`. I changed the local language of TYPO3 using this:

```
config.locale_all = nl_NL
```

This solves the problem while displaying `List` of news, but when I try to display a `Date Menu`, it takes the default to English.

Maybe because the ViewHelpers I used for displaying List is default FLUID and the ViewHelpers used for displaying Date Menu are something else(They use translate key. Default View which comes with tx_news)

How do I change the language of tx_news to the language I desired to?

Answer (score 1):

`config.locale_all` is basically used to change format of dates (more info on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html)

In order to get localized labels, you need:

1. To download localization packages in Backend using the Language module
2. To set up your website with the language you want, using `config.language` (and possibly `config.sys_language_uid` if your website is going to be multilingual, then you would have to create sys_language records at root as well)

Please have a look at the frontend localization guide:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/